# Why I am not able to add Data to Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add data to a document to Firebase Firestore. I've added a collection named users to it. Also, the read/write permissions are open for now. I'm following this doc. And I'm not able to add data to document only on this Activity. on other activity, I can add data easily

Here is my Code:

```
    package com.example.ewulife;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.annotations.Nullable;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
    import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
    import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
    import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
    import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    
    import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
    
    public class UserInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        Button next;
        FirebaseFirestore fstore;
        FirebaseAuth fAuth;
        String userID;
        Spinner bloodgroup;
        RadioGroup radioGroup;
        RadioButton gender;
        ArrayList<String> arrayList_blood;
        ArrayAdapter<String> rr_blood;
        EditText fullname,Mobile,credit,semister,cgpa;
        String Fullname, Blood, Gender;
        ImageView condition, upload;
        CircleImageView profile_image;
        StorageReference storageReference;
        double cred2,semi2,cgpa2;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_info);
    
            fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            fstore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    
            storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            bloodgroup = findViewById(R.id.spinner00);
            fullname = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName00);
            Mobile =findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName200);
            next = findViewById(R.id.button1300);
            upload = findViewById(R.id.imageView1600);
            profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image300);
            credit = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
            semister = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal);
            cgpa = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal2);
            profile_image.setOnClickListener(this);
            upload.setOnClickListener(this);
            next.setOnClickListener(this);
    
            {
                radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.gender00);
                arrayList_blood = new ArrayList<>();
                arrayList_blood.add("Select");
                arrayList_blood.add("BBA");
                arrayList_blood.add("BSS in Economics");
                arrayList_blood.add("BA in English");
                arrayList_blood.add("LL.B (Hon’s)");
                arrayList_blood.add("BSS in Sociology");
                arrayList_blood.add("BSS in ISLM");
                arrayList_blood.add("BS in Applied Statistics");
                arrayList_blood.add("B.Sc. in ETE");
                arrayList_blood.add("B.Sc. in ICE");
                arrayList_blood.add("B.Sc. in CSE");
                arrayList_blood.add("B.Sc. in EEE");
                arrayList_blood.add("B.Pharm.");
                arrayList_blood.add("B.Sc. in GEB");
                arrayList_blood.add("B.Sc. in Civil Engineering");
                arrayList_blood.add("B.Sc. in ECE");
    
                arrayList_blood.add("Select");
                arrayList_blood.add("MBA");
                arrayList_blood.add("EMBA");
                arrayList_blood.add("MDS");
                arrayList_blood.add("MSS in Economics");
                arrayList_blood.add("MA in English");
                arrayList_blood.add("MA in ELT");
                arrayList_blood.add("LL.M");
                arrayList_blood.add("MPRHGD");
                arrayList_blood.add("PPDM");
                arrayList_blood.add("MS in Applied Statistics");
                arrayList_blood.add("MS in TE");
                arrayList_blood.add("MS in CSE");
                arrayList_blood.add("MS in APE");
                arrayList_blood.add("M. Pharm");
    
            }
            rr_blood = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_blood);
            bloodgroup.setAdapter(rr_blood);
            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            gender = findViewById(selectedId);
    
            StorageReference profRef = storageReference.child("ewuuser/"+userID+"profile.jpg");
            profRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Picasso.get().load(uri).into(profile_image);
                    //Picasso.get().load(uri).into(edit_pic);
    
    
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @androidx.annotation.Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 1000) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri imageuri = data.getData();
    
                    profile_image.setImageURI(imageuri);
                    //back_pic.setImageURI(imageuri);
    
                    uploadImageToFirebase(imageuri);
    
                }
            }
        }
    
        private void uploadImageToFirebase(Uri imageUri) {
            //upload
            final StorageReference fileRef = storageReference.child("ewuuser/" + userID + "profile.jpg");
            fileRef.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            Picasso.get().load(uri).into(profile_image);
                            //Picasso.get().load(uri).into(back_pic);
    
                            //progressBar_prof.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
    
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@androidx.annotation.NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "File is not Uploaded" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //progressBar_prof.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    
            if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView1600) {
                Intent openGalery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(openGalery, 1000);
    
            }
            if (v.getId() == R.id.button1300) {
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                gender = findViewById(selectedId);
                final String name = fullname.getText().toString();
                final String number = Mobile.getText().toString();
                if (name.isEmpty()) {
                    fullname.setError("Name Required");
                    return;
                }
    
                if (gender == null) {
    
                    Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "Selected Gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                String blood_group = bloodgroup.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (blood_group.equals("Select")) {
                    Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "Selected Department", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                String gen = gender.getText().toString();
                final String cre = credit.getText().toString();
                if(cre.isEmpty()){
                    credit.setError("Enter Valid Credit");
                    Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "Enter Valid Credit or leave it blank if you are new", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if((Double.parseDouble(cre))>200){
                    credit.setError("Enter valid Credit");
                    Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "Enter valid CGPA or leave it blank if you are new", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
    
                final String semi = semister.getText().toString();
                if(semi.isEmpty()){
                    semister.setError("Enter valid semister");
                    Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "Enter valid Semister or leave it blank if you are new", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if((Double.parseDouble(semi))>20){
                    semister.setError("Enter valid Semister");
                    Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "Enter valid CGPA or leave it blank if you are new", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
    
                final String cgpa1 = cgpa.getText().toString();
    
                if(cgpa1.isEmpty()){
                    cgpa.setError("Enter valid CGPA");
                    Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "Enter valid CGPA or leave it blank if you are new", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if((Double.parseDouble(cgpa1))>4){
                    cgpa.setError("Enter valid CGPA");
                    Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "Enter valid CGPA or leave it blank if you are new", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                final DocumentReference documentReference3 = fstore.collection("EWU_student").document(userID);
//here error 242 //                documentReference3.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot1, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e2) {
    
    
                        Map<String, Object> user1 = new HashMap<>();
                        user1.put("Name",name);
                        user1.put("EWU_ID",number);
                        user1.put("Credit",cre);
                        user1.put("Semister",semi);
                        user1.put("Program",blood_group);
                        user1.put("Gender",gen);
                        user1.put("USER ID",userID);
                        user1.put("Drop",'0');
                     //   user1.put("Profile Photo","ewuuser/"+userID+"profile.jpg");
                        user1.put("CGPA",cgpa1);
    
    
  //here error show 260//                      documentReference3.set(user1).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    
    
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "User Updated" + userID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(UserInfoActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
    
    
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "User not updated 3 " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
    
    
                    }
                });
    
    
            }
        }
        }
```

In Logs I see only these thing and can not under the problem:

```
2021-03-20 15:15:05.637 8348-8348/com.example.ewulife E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ewulife, PID: 8348
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not serialize object. Characters are not supported, please use Strings (found in field 'Drop')
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serializeError(CustomClassMapper.java:555)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:133)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:140)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:104)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:78)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.convertAndParseDocumentData(UserDataReader.java:231)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseSetData(UserDataReader.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(DocumentReference.java:167)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(DocumentReference.java:147)
        **at com.example.ewulife.UserInfoActivity$4.onEvent(UserInfoActivity.java:260)
        at com.example.ewulife.UserInfoActivity$4.onEvent(UserInfoActivity.java:242)**
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(DocumentReference.java:505)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(AsyncEventListener.java:42)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**the error part is**

```
    **at com.example.ewulife.UserInfoActivity$4.onEvent(UserInfoActivity.java:260)
    at com.example.ewulife.UserInfoActivity$4.onEvent(UserInfoActivity.java:242)**
```

**[There are the sreenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlTaf.png)
[There are the screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ivf1.png)
**

Comment: The error message seems reasonably clear to me: you're using a `char` value for `Drop` here: `user1.put("Drop",'0');` You need to use a string value instead: `user1.put("Drop", "0");`

Comment: but i this before. also on other activity........but it work......but in this activity it is not working

Comment: Well, we can't tell what's going on with code we can't see, but the error message is reasonably clear and it's pretty simple to fix, so I suggest you at least try it...

Comment: Besides that, if you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **350** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code user1.put("Drop","0") instead of this
user1.put("Drop",'0')

Comment: OMG, I did not look at this simple mistake. Thanks. how stupid I am